# Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline - Issues with deleting jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

**Use case:** Using Jenkinsfile to auto create builds for branches

**Summary:** 
For a variety of reasons sometimes the Jenkins master fails to connect to the SCM server.  When this occurs Jenkins deletes that job directory on master, because it no longer sees the branches. However, the slaves are not cleaned up and so they still have the old workspace paths (which are uniquely named based on the build # in my setup).  When the Jenkins master reconnects to the SCM server, it recreates a new job folder on master, and the build counter is reset to #1.

This creates the following **issues:**

1. When a build starts, it executes on a slave.  Since master has a new counter the job is #1.  But this path may already exist from a previous build on that slave, so the artifact is built with content that was checked out for the original old build (i.e. maven uses the /target directory inside the workspace which already existed from previous build). So the end result is an artifact that potentially has the wrong code.
2. This can create build storms.  After the connection issues are resolved, Jenkins will see all the repositories and branches with Jenkinsfiles and start to build them. So in a setup of let's say 20 repositories with 10 branches each, this will create 200 new builds.  This increases with additional repositories and branches.  This is obviously not desired.

**Solutions:**

1. One quick solution I can think of is to update the Jenkinsfile to delete the workspace if it exists before running the job inside of it.  But this is just a work around. I would not want to mask the connection issues and would like to retain the actual build history of a pipeline (not have it keep erasing itself).
2. Minimize connection issues.  This obviously will not always be guaranteed though.  Plus sometimes maintenance must force servers offline.  While I can construct maintenance in a way to limit or work around such issues,  there still will be rare cases where downtime is required across the board.  It would be best if Jenkins could handle this use case.

I'm curious if anyone has ran into this issue and what the thoughts are on this problem?

Comment: I didn't run into this with Github (maybe didn't notice b/c we don't run that many builds). You have under _Orphaned Item Strategy_ the option _Discard old items_ checked, have you? What about increasing _Days to keep old items_ so that it doesn't get deleted immediately? Just as a workaround...

Comment: None of those are set.  The idea being that jobs live as long as the branch does.  When we promote the branch (merge to master) the branch is deleted, so when the next scan runs, the job is deleted as well.  The issue is when the scan runs during a connection issue.  It sees the branch as deleted I guess, so it delets the job.

Comment: any CloudBees guys able to offer advice?

Comment: Have you checked the issue tracker?

Comment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34177.  This would save me from manually cleaning up anything when the issue occurs.  But the branches still exist and would not want the job history deleted until the branch was.  I can understand the argument to handle connectivity issues which may ultimately be the solution.  But I cannot think they will never occur.  But maybe plugin could be enhanced.  Such as caching the branch/repo name and job history and if it sees a new branch, it checks to see if that once existed before in that repo, and if so - restores job history.